# How to check if code is excuting on iphone device or watch device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2, watchos

As UIDevice is not available on watchOS, I am wondering how to detect which device it is for watch specific code execution in the libraries which are executed on both OS (iOS as well as WatchOS). We could use particular class from watch_os and see if thats available, however just wanted to know if there is anything other than that technique. Which class is safe to use in that case?

Comment: You can wrap code that you only want to run on watch in an `#if TARGET_OS_WATCH` `#endif` block.

Comment: Awesome ! This helps !

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Swift and one of your library classes is called MyClass.

compile this into your iOS target:

```
extension MyClass {
    func isWatch() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

compile this into your watch target:

```
extension MyClass {
    func isWatch() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Now you have a function that is available in all targets and returns a different Value.

The function returns a constant in each target so the compiler can optimize .

Comment: I am not using swift. :(